# Reuse Pig Groups in nested FOREACH statement

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to group records together, calculate the average of SCORE1, filter out the lower half of the scores, and compute their average of SCORE2. Obviously I can calculate the summary statistics, and rejoin them to the original dataset, but I'd prefer to use the intermediate grouped values.

**Example Input**

```
ID,GROUPBY,SCORE1,SCORE2
1,A,58.8,67.3
2,A,85.2,76.3
3,B,49.1,90.7
4,B,78.3,99.8
```

**Pig Script**

```
records = load 'example.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (ID,GROUPBY,SCORE1,SCORE2);
grouped = group records by GROUPBY;
avgscore = foreach grouped GENERATE group AS GROUPBY, AVG(records.SCORE1) AS AVGSCORE;
joined = join grouped BY group, avgscore BY GROUPBY USING 'replicated';
results = foreach joined {
    scores = foreach records generate SCORE1,SCORE2;
    low = FILTER scores by SCORE1 < avgscore.AVGSCORE;
    GENERATE GROUPBY, AVG(low.SCORE2);
};
dump results;
```

**Desired Output**

```
A    67.3
B    90.7
```

However this gives me a result of java.lang.Exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (A,72.0), 2nd :(B,63.7)

Comment: 1] You are accessing AVGSCORE as avgscore.AVGSCORE, while it should be accessed as avgscore::AVGSCORE. 2]
its not clear what are you trying to achieve thought the example code. can you pls give the sample i/p and o/p?
3] GROUP inside nested FOREACH operation inside is not supported by Pig.

Comment: I've added the desired output per your request.

Comment: I quite did not understand the question yet. What do you mean by "calculate the average of SCORE1, filter out the lower half of the scores,"... Do you mean filter out the rows with SCORE1 less than avg(SCORE1) or simply filter out half the rows with least SCORE1 value?

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially grouping two different data structures in line 4.
You are joining grouped (which is grouped) with avgscore (which should be flattened).

You should be doing:

```
joined = join records BY GROUPBY, avgscore BY GROUPBY USING 'replicated';
```

edit:
I would rewrite like this to avoid confusion (since there will be two GROUPBYs)

```
records = load 'example.csv' Using PigStorage(',') AS (ID,GROUPBY,SCORE1,SCORE2);
grouped = group records by GROUPBY;
avgscore = foreach grouped GENERATE group AS GROUPBY, AVG(records.SCORE1) AS AVGSCORE;
joined = join records BY GROUPBY, avgscore BY GROUPBY USING 'replicated';
joined_reduced = foreach joined generate ID, records::GROUPBY as GROUPBY, AVGSCORE, SCORE1, SCORE2;
filter_joined = filter joined_reduced by (SCORE1 > AVGSCORE);
grouped2 = group filter_joined by GROUPBY;
result = foreach grouped2 generate flatten (group), AVG(filter_joined.SCORE2) as low_avg;

dump result;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being picky, but I was curious if there is a possible way to perform this computation using the already grouped bags. It sounds like if I want to do this I will need to write a UDF or, as your example specifies, regroup the individual records. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean since I did not add additional joins.

Comment: Maybe you mean additional group by. You need to group by every time you take an average since you need to specify how to find the average. So since you are taking the average twice, there are two group bys. There is really no need for a UDF.